Make Git aware of moved files (at time of a merge conflict)
Scenario
You create a new branch, move a file, and modify its contents. Simultaneously, on a different branch, another developer makes changes to the same file without moving it. When their branch is merged before yours, you face a merge conflict.
Problem
When merging, Git flags the conflict for the file you moved. It marks the file as "deleted" by you and "modified" by them. This happens because Git is unable to recognize that you moved the file and made extensive changes. Instead, Git interprets this as you having deleted the old file and created a new one, leading to a merge conflict.
Ideas

Rename Detection (-M flag):
Git’s -M flag controls how it detects renames. However, if a file has undergone significant changes, rename detection may fail, as in your case.

Moving Files via Git:
Using git mv ensures that Git tracks renames. However, since the file was moved manually, Git did not register the move. A potential solution might be rewriting history to use git mv and force-pushing, but this is only feasible if rewriting history is an option.


Question
Currently, I am resolving a merge conflict. I have addressed conflicts in half of the files, but for the remaining files, Git incorrectly displays them as "deleted by me" and "modified by them". This makes conflict resolution cumbersome. Is there a way to "recover" from this situation so Git can detect the moved files as renamed, thus simplifying the conflict resolution?


Using git mv ensures that Git tracks renames. This is incorrect. Git has no way to explicitly track renames. git mv is a convenience for renaming the file and staging the changes.

23 renamed files is a lot. How much work is being done in that branch?

Hi, this is just a fraction of what I just dealt with. This branch will not be merged before another, which changes about 120 files. The branch I am working at is doing quite a lot, moving files, code and pretty much rewrites everything.

I suspect this is a dup.

First, let's clear this up.

Using git mv ensures that Git tracks renames.

It doesn't. Git has no mechanism to explicitly track renames. git mv old new renames the files and tracks the changes just like doing it manually.
Git only tracks renames by looking at the contents of the files. You could tell the merge to try harder with -X find-renames=50% or similar, but this can only go so far. It's better to change your process to avoid Git's weaknesses and play to Git's strengths.
Do it in two related branches.
A great many merge problems come down to doing too much in one branch.
For example, let's say you're working on a feature and find it would be a lot easier if you renamed and refactored a bunch of classes. Renaming the classes requires renaming their files.
If you did this and the feature in one branch, you're going to have a mess. Files will have been renamed and then changed to implement the feature making it difficult for Git to detect the rename.
Instead, do it in two branches. First do the refactoring; this does the minimum of change to rename the classes, rename the files, and change references to those classes. Then do the feature work on top of that.
1 - 2 - 3 [main]
         \
          A - B - C [refactor]
                   \
                    D - E - F [feature]

It's ok to work on the feature branch while the refactor branch is being reviewed. I would say the feature branch is "anticipating" the refactor branch will be merged.
It's likely there will be changes to the refactor branch during review. In that case the feature branch should be rebased on top of the refactor branch.
For example, let's say review results in more commits to the refactor branch...
1 - 2 - 3 [main]
         \
          A - B - C - Z - Y [refactor]
                   \
                    D - E - F [feature]

You'd rebase just the feature branch onto the new tip of the refactor branch. git rebase --onto refactor refactor feature says to rewrite all the commits in feature which are not in refactor (same as refactor..feature) onto refactor.
$ git rebase --onto refactor refactor feature

1 - 2 - 3 [main]
         \
          A - B - C - Z - Y [refactor]
                           \
                            D1 - E1 - F1 [feature]

Once refactor has been merged into main...
1 - 2 - 3 ------------------[main]
         \                 /
          A - B - C - Z - Y
                           \
                            D1 - E1 - F1 [feature]

...rebase feature onto main and continue developing normally.
$ git switch feature
$ git rebase main

1 - 2 - 3 ------------------[main]
         \                 /\
          A - B - C - Z - Y  D2 - E2 - F2 [feature]                         


Split the existing branch
What about your situation where the branch wasn't written that way? You can rewrite history to turn it into two branches.
If the commits are well written, following conventional commits and doing one thing per commit, you should be able to do an interactive rebase and reorder the commits to put all the refactoring and file renaming commits at the start of the branch.
It's not likely to be that simple. There will probably be conflicts. If commit discipline was bad, you might have to edit commits to split them into refactoring and feature commits. This might not save any time, but it will be a more orderly process and part of your review.

Thanks. There are two problems. I have one commit to work with and am currently in a merge. The other issue is, that I do not want to abort my current merge resolution progress. I tried stashing, but that also didn't seem to work properly. Your suggestions are good and might prevent a future situation like this, but they do not solve the current situation. I was hoping for a way to tell Git explicitly that this file is that file now, but it seems there is no way to do that, and the only choice Git has is to match files by content. But to use -X, I would have to abort my current progress.

@oSumAtrIX 1) "I have one commit to work with..." Split the commit into logical pieces, if possible, and educate the person responsible on commit discipline. 2) "I do not want to abort my current merge resolution..." Clone another copy of the repo and start another merge. 3) Consider rejecting the change and tell the person who wrote it to untangle their mess.

@oSumAtrIX To split the mega-commit, git switch thebranch; git reset --soft HEAD~. This will move thebranch back one commit and leave you with all the changes staged. You can then unstage them, stage one logical change (git add -p helps here), stash the rest, test it, commit, and unstash. Repeat until all the refactoring changes are committed and make a refactoring branch at that commit. Then repeat until all the feature changes are committed.

Again, thanks for the recommendation, but I am not here for best commit practices. I am here to understand how to recover from such a situation, and commit practices do not help out of this current situation.
I am currently in a merge; switching branches or resetting would abort it, which I want to avoid to not lose the progress.

I am sure there will be corner cases to this workaround but it should work for most cases.
Create a temporary branch where you will do the merge. Rename back the renamed files. Do the merge, you should not get those tree conflicts, right? When you are done, rename the files back to what they have to be. So, 3 commits all in all, right? Now, run this (use a meaningful comment):
git commit-tree -p @~3 -p the-othet-branch -m "hiding all complexity" @^{tree}

That will produce a commit ID with a merge that is like magic happened.... Place your real branch on this commit and live happily ever after.

Thanks. There are two problems associated with this solution. Firstival, I am currently in a merge. To pull off your suggestion, I would need to get rid of the hard work that has already been done by aborting it. The second problem is that I would need to invest a lot of work into renaming the files; this is almost as tedious as not doing it because I am working with hundreds of files. The issue originated from not being able to tell Git about the renames explicitly. Instead, Git is left alone to figure out renamed files by matching the content.

@oSumAtrIX Again, you can keep your current merge work by cloning another copy of the repository to experiment with.

.... Or using a separate working tree on the same repo.
